# Center inline divs on resize?

Tags: html, css, resize

I am quite new to html and CSS. And came across a big issue recently.

I have 2 divisions in another division. Both of those divs have few buttons etc, and are next to each other - inline. But, when I try to minimize my chrome window, 2nd div moves under 1st, which is great. But, they both are aligned to left of the screen. How could I make them stick to center?

Since I don't know how to explain better, here are some images.

How the divisions look like:

[image]

What happens when I resize browser:

[image]

What I want to happen with resize:

[image]

I sincerely hope someone can offer some type of suggestions.

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have any code you can post? Would be helpful to see what you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center inline elements by adding text-align: center; to the container element.

```
.container {
     text-align: center;
}
```

and if you don't want the text within the elements centered then...

```
.container * {
     text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this simple solution fixed it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Give the outer `div` (the parent container) a `text-align: center`.

Since the child divs are `inline`, the [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) property on the parent can control their alignment.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming from your question that you are interested in horizontal-centering and not vertical centering as well.

I am also quite new to HTML / CSS, but over the past few weeks I have found the flex facility to be quite useful.  Using https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ has proven to be most helpful.

The following HTML and CSS files illustrate how flex can be used to achieve the desired effect.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">

        <meta name    = "viewport"
              content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0"
        >

        <link href = "CSS/Example.css"
              rel  = "stylesheet"
              type = "text/css"
        >
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id    = "entire-page"
             class = "empty-cell"
        >
            <div id    = "inner-div-1"
                 class = "empty-cell"
            >
            </div>

            <div id    = "inner-div-2"
                 class = "empty-cell"
            >
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html,
*
{
    border      : 0;
    box-sizing  : border-box;
    margin    : 0;
    padding     : 0;
}

.empty-cell
{
    min-height : 1px;
}

#entire-page 
{
    align-content    : flex-start;
    background-color : blue;
    display          : flex;
    flex-wrap        : wrap;
    float            : left;
    height           : 100vh;
    justify-content  : center;
    width            : 100%;
}

#inner-div-1
{
    background-color : red;
    display : block;
    float : left;
    height           : 200px;
    width            : 400px;
}

#inner-div-2
{
    background-color : yellow;
    display : block;
    float : left;
    height           : 200px;
    width            : 400px;
}
```

I used flex-wrap : wrap so that the second div would wrap onto the next line when there was no longer enough room for both on one line.

I used justify-content : center to horizontally center the contents of the flex-box (namely, the two inner-div's).

I used align-content : flex-start to keep the two inner-div's together when displaying them vertically, otherwise they would have been evenly spaced across the entire flex-box.

If you have any questions about this answer, then please feel free to ask them.